Why don't people move to swing states temporarily to have a more significant impact on the election?
In most states, the requirement to be a resident and therein vote is to be living in the state for 183 days of that calendar (or tax) year.
For many upper-class individuals, doing that once every four years shouldn't be too difficult, and if they normally live in a state that always votes blue like California, or always red like Alabama, doing so would be incredibly useful.
Does this phenomenon occur, and if not, why not?
And no, I'm not referring to the vote fraud espoused in this question, my question asks about people who do so entirely within the limits of the law.

I think there's a valid distinction here between the question this is closed as a duplicate of and what you're asking, but you'd probably need to edit the question to make that clearer.  It seems to me that the other question is asking about a short term stay and this one is about a permanent move.  Unless you're suggesting that they move, wait half a year for the election, then move back, which is yet another category of impracticality.

Just to illustrate some of the scale involved, the state that had the lowest difference in votes was Arizona, with 10457 votes. So you're talking about 10's of thousands of people moving. The 5 states with the lowest difference between the votes are Arizona, Georgia, Wisconsin, Nevada, and Alaska and have a combined total of 112,687 vote differences. The swing states, GA, NV, WI, MI, AZ, and PA have a total of 311,257 from 2020's election. That's a lot of people to move, and would definitely have an economic impact beyond voting.

And if the other side figures it out, they will also start moving. So if 112,692 people supporting one party were to move, there would be 100,000 supporting the other party moving as well.

Put simply, this idea isn't remotely close to cost-effective. Meaningfully affecting an election in a swing state would involve the coordinated action of thousands of people, all of whom would need to be willing and financially able to give up jobs, houses, and personal lives in their home state and obtain new jobs, houses, and personal lives in a swing state. Moreover, their new housing would have to be allocated correctly across the swing state; Senate seats aside, there would be no point in people moving from a blue state to an already blue district in a swing state, or to a district so red that the numeric advantage is impractical to overcome. It would require huge amounts of money, effort, and organization to accomplish anything.
And note, this money, effort, and organization would not go unnoticed. Not only would red-state political actors scream about it as a cynical manipulation of electoral politics (which, frankly, is what it would be), but local citizens would see it as a kind of invasion, like the Rajneeshpuram cult that took over a town in Oregon. There would be friction, to say the least. So not only would these people need to have the exceptional financial means and political motivation to move themselves, their families, and everything they own to an algorithmically determined location, they'd also face hostility and aggression from the new community.
Honestly, I'd be surprised if we could find a handful of people in the US willing to throw this much of themselves into an election — much less every election, every four years — I can't imagine we'd find enough people to make a meaningful difference.

You touched on this with the "facing hostility and aggression" part but in addition there would be an extremely high risk of motivating undecided and non-voters to vote the other way to try to counteract this.  I can easily believe an effort like this would actually end up garnering more votes for the opposition than it would provide for your own side.

And rather than spending the money on this to get one vote, it's probably much more cost-effective to spend on advertising and get-out-the-vote campaigns. It would also be more cost-effective to send opposition voters on vacation for election day.

@StuartF Much better idea really. So 120,000 voters get an email “you won a two day holiday in San Francisco” and it’s not a scam but real.

@gnasher729: except you'd have to send them for the entire early voting period, and somehow block them from mail-in voting. How much would it cost to give 120,000 people a month+ vacation to an island without mail service?
